# amcharts the bars are coming in reverse direction

Tags: javascript, html, charts, amcharts

I am working with Amcharts, The chart is dealing with the below dataset in order to get them rendered in bars. I am able to render the chart, but the BARS are poping down(top to down), As per the value axis (Time of the day), it should pop up ideally.

The data format :

```
var chartData = [
{        "batchName":"dgfhdfgf",
        "expectedEndTime": "23/10/18 23:30",
        "actualEndTime": "23/10/18 23:37",
    },
     {
        "batchName":"gdfgs",
        "expectedEndTime": "24/10/18 00:05",
        "actualEndTime": "24/10/18 00:05",
    },
    ------------------
    ------------------
```

The configuration is :

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "zoomOutText": '',
    "columnSpacing": 0,
    "dataDateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN",
    "legend": {
        "horizontalGap": 30,
        "maxColumns": 30,
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "markerSize": 10,
        "padding": 10,
        "valueText": ""
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
            "id": "v1",
            "position": "left",
            "unitPosition": "left",
            "axisColor": "#472F52",
            "title": "Time of the Day",
            "type": "date",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "markPeriodChange": false,
            "autoGridCount": false,
            "minimumDate": "23/10/18 21:00",
            "maximumDate": "24/10/18 23:59",
            "gridCount": 20,
            "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN",
            // "minPeriod": "ss",                               
        }

    ],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
            "id": "g1",
            "valueAxis": "v1",
            "fixedColumnWidth": 15,
            "type": "column",
            "fillAlphas": 0.9,
            "lineThickness": 1.5,
            "lineColor": "#0D338C",
            "bulletBorderColor": "#0D338C",
            "valueField": "expectedEndTime",
            "title": "Expected Path",
            "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN A",
            "labelText": "[[labelExpected]]",
            "labelColorField": "labelColor2",
            "balloonText": "Expected EndTime : <b>[[value]]</b>"
        },
        {
            "id": "g2",
            "valueAxis": "v1",
            "fillAlphas": 0.9,
            "fixedColumnWidth": 15,
            "type": "column",
            "lineThickness": 1.5,
            "lineColor": "#C63F05",
            "bulletBorderColor": "#C63F05",
            "valueField": "actualEndTime",
            "title": "Actual Path",
            "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN A",
            "labelColor": "blue",
            "labelText": "[[labelActual]]",
            "labelColorField": "labelColor1",
            "balloonText": "Actual EndTime : <b>[[value]]</b>"
        }
    ],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD",
        "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
        "cursorColor": "#000000",
        "fullWidth": true,
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "batchName",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "axisColor": "#472F52",
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "gridCount": 1000,
        "title": "MRNG Batch Stages",
        "labelRotation": 30
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "borderRadius": "10px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "pdfMake": {
            "content": ["'<Name of the Metric to be displayed dynamically>'",
                "                     ", "from <startDate> To <endDate>", {
                    "image": "reference", //exported image
                    "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
                }
            ]
        },
        "legend": {
            "position": "bottom", // or "right", "bottom" and "left" are possible
            "width": 200, // optional
            "height": 200 // optional
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1r7fq2d/17/)

Not sure, what is going wrong as the bars are coming up in wrong direction. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [date formatting documentation](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/), two-digit years are *not* supported in v3's `dataDateFormat` (note the formats with an asterisk don't work). You have to use four-digit years in your data and adjust your `dataDateFormat` accordingly.

Updated demo below (note you need `JJ` for 00-23 hours, not `KK`):

```js
var chartData = [{
    "batchName": "dgfhdfgf",
    "expectedEndTime": "23/10/2018 23:30",
    "actualEndTime": "23/10/2018 23:37",
  },
  {
    "batchName": "gdfgs",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 00:05",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 00:05",
  },
  {
    "batchName": "ytryedfbg(GS)",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 00:48",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 00:54"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "jghjty",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 00:54",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 01:20"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "hgjghj (all)",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 01:01",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 01:02"
  },


  {
    "batchName": "mghjghj",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 01:35",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 01:27"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "dfd",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 03:15",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 04:58",
    "labelExpected": "03:15",
    "labelActual": "04:58",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "rts",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:00",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 04:55"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "asdasd",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:18",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:39"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "dfasdf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:25"
  }, {
    "batchName": "dfggf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:41",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:49"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "dfgd",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 06:00",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:57"
  },

  {
    "batchName": "fgsdfg",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 06:18",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 04:46",
    "labelExpected": "06:18",
    "labelActual": "04:46",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "ghdf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 06:31",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 06:31"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "ioklj",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 07:18",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 08:58",
    "labelExpected": "07:18",
    "labelActual": "08:58",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },

  {
    "batchName": "klhjoi",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 07:38",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 05:57"
  },

  {
    "batchName": "jdfhfgth",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 08:00",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 09:03",
    "labelExpected": "08:00",
    "labelActual": "09:03",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "gdfhfhg",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 10:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 10:56"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "fdgsgdf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 11:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 12:37"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "dgfasdf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 11:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 17:18"
  },


  {
    "batchName": "tawetrgtsdf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 11:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 16:30",
    "labelExpected": "11:30",
    "labelActual": "16:30",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "efrwearf",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 11:30",
    "actualEndTime": "24/10/2018 17:38",
    "labelExpected": "11:30",
    "labelActual": "17:38",
    "labelColor1": "red",
    "labelColor2": "blue"
  },
  {
    "batchName": "fdsfsdg",
    "expectedEndTime": "24/10/2018 16:00",
    "actualEndTime": ""
  }
];
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "zoomOutText": '',
  "columnSpacing": 0,
  "dataDateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY JJ:NN",
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 30,
    "maxColumns": 30,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10,
    "padding": 10,
    "valueText": ""
  },
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueAxes": [{
      "id": "v1",
      "position": "left",
      "unitPosition": "left",
      "axisColor": "#472F52",
      "title": "Time of the Day",
      "type": "date",
      "axisThickness": 2,
      "markPeriodChange": false,
      "autoGridCount": false,
      "minimumDate": "23/10/2018 21:00",
      "maximumDate": "24/10/2018 23:59",
      "gridCount": 20,
      //"dateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY KK:NN",
      // "minPeriod": "ss",        
    }

  ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
      "id": "g1",
      "valueAxis": "v1",
      "fixedColumnWidth": 15,
      "type": "column",
      "fillAlphas": 0.9,
      "lineThickness": 1.5,
      "lineColor": "#0D338C",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#0D338C",
      "valueField": "expectedEndTime",
      "title": "Expected Path",
      "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN A",
      "labelText": "[[labelExpected]]",
      "labelColorField": "labelColor2",
      "balloonText": "Expected EndTime : <b>[[value]]</b>"
    },
    {
      "id": "g2",
      "valueAxis": "v1",
      "fillAlphas": 0.9,
      "fixedColumnWidth": 15,
      "type": "column",
      "lineThickness": 1.5,
      "lineColor": "#C63F05",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#C63F05",
      "valueField": "actualEndTime",
      "title": "Actual Path",
      "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YY KK:NN A",
      "labelColor": "blue",
      "labelText": "[[labelActual]]",
      "labelColorField": "labelColor1",
      "balloonText": "Actual EndTime : <b>[[value]]</b>"
    }
  ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD",
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "cursorColor": "#000000",
    "fullWidth": true,
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "batchName",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisColor": "#472F52",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "gridCount": 1000,
    "title": "MRNG Batch Stages",
    "labelRotation": 30
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "borderRadius": "10px",
    "text-align": "center",
    "pdfMake": {
      "content": ["'<Name of the Metric to be displayed dynamically>'",
        "                     ", "from <startDate> To <endDate>", {
          "image": "reference", //exported image
          "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
        }
      ]
    },
    "legend": {
      "position": "bottom", // or "right", "bottom" and "left" are possible
      "width": 200, // optional
      "height": 200 // optional
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me.Now, Just wondering if I can avoid the collision of the data labels. I tried **labelRotation, but didn't fits well. Here is https://jsfiddle.net/z1r7fq2d/19/, what i tried. Any suggestion please.

Comment: There isn't a way to avoid label overlap in amCharts outside of labelRotation and labelOffset. You'll have to rely on balloons and disable labels if neither of those options are sufficient for you.

Comment: If we disable the labels, then can it be possible to make the balloon displayed for multiple bars all the times(irrespective of the mouse hover). Please suggest, as I need to show these values as part of capturing the screenshot of the chart too.

Comment: Balloons are only triggered by mouseover and can only show on one datapoint/category at any time.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I tried labelRotation like in https://jsfiddle.net/z1r7fq2d/19/, but it's getting messed up with the bars. Just  wondering, if we can set the values little up.

Comment: Use [labelOffset](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelOffset).

Comment: thanks, combination of labelRotation and labelOffset worked for me.